# How to query for email addresses listed under Email-To-Case routing addresses?

Tags: email2case

**Use Case**
I am replacing the standard Email publisher action on case with a custom VF page using the apex:emailPubilsher tag. For certain cases, we need to be able to include an extra "From" address as an option.

**Problem**
The problem is when you specify the "fromAddresses" option in the emailPublisher tag, it replaces the entire list with what is supplied. I don't want to replace the list, just append a value to it.

**TLDR**
I am looking for a way to query for the email addresses listed under the Routing Address section of the Email-To-Case Settings page. Specifically those listed as Email2Case.

**What I've tried**
I know the OrgWideEmailAddress object is not what I'm looking for here. I did find a [CaseSettings](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_meta/Content/meta_casesettings.htm) description but it doesn't seem like I can access that from within SFDC.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Could you get at that EmailToCaseRoutingAddress object through the Apex MDAPI wrapper? https://github.com/financialforcedev/apex-mdapi

Comment: Will look into that and report back

Comment: Client ended up changing their requirement so didn't get a chance to test this. I'll see if I get time to test it on my own to help anyone else who may run into this issue in the future and post my results

Answer (score 1):

You can query the case-to-email address using the EmailServicesAddress object.

```
SELECT Id,AuthorizedSenders,EmailDomainName,IsActive,LocalPart FROM EmailServicesAddress
```

The LocalPart plus the EmailDomainName make up the routing email address.

Reference:

- [Salesforce SOAP API Developer Guide: EmailServicesAddress](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_emailservicesaddress.htm)

Answer (score 0):

The exact query to get all the related will look something similar.

`SELECT Id, IsActive, LocalPart, EmailDomainName, AuthorizedSenders, RunAsUserId, FunctionId, Function.FunctionName, DeveloperName, CreatedById, CreatedDate, LastModifiedById, LastModifiedDate, SystemModstamp FROM EmailServicesAddress where Function.FunctionName='EmailToCase'`

and the LocalPart plus the EmailDomainName make up the routing email address.